# R, ggplot geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have got a `data.frame` which contains root lengths per diameter classes. There are 43 rows which represent the sampled individuals, and 55 columns which represent my root diameter classes (ex:0.04233, 0.04233, 0.04233, 0.08467, 0.08467...) except for one which is called "Esp" (for species).

this represents a portion of my table:

```
          Esp 0.04233 0.08467   0.127 0.1693  0.2117   0.254  0.2963  0.3387 
Ag_T0_8    Ag  260.14  931.84  310.94  69.13  26.374  35.772  13.885  18.542 
Ag_T0_11   Ag  237.32 1086.32  653.33 274.79 136.017  95.038  57.743  36.449 
Ca_T0_5    Ca   45.30   94.70   66.55  43.77  16.298   7.112   3.768   3.979  
Ca_T0_15   Ca  568.43 1183.01  621.01 351.90 125.603  93.409 111.506  65.257
Tg_T0_159  Tg  608.12  339.09  132.55  39.16   9.102  10.795  11.176   6.900  
Tg_T0_160  Tg  332.15  193.08   61.55  33.82  11.388   6.011   4.657   3.598
```

I would like to get a histogram of the distribution of root diameter by species with the root diameter classes on the X-axis, and the cumulative frequencies on the Y-axis, with 3 different colors, one for each of my three groups ("Ag", "Ca", "Tg").

I tried to make a table with cumulative frequencies of roots by diameter classes but it doesn't work either with ggplot. I don't think it is a good way to calculate the frequencies by myself...

I hope you will understand what is my problem.

Has someone an idea, please ?

Thank you so much if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Esp 0.04233 0.08467   0.127 0.1693  0.2117   0.254  0.2963  0.3387 
Ag_T0_8    Ag  260.14  931.84  310.94  69.13  26.374  35.772  13.885  18.542 
Ag_T0_11   Ag  237.32 1086.32  653.33 274.79 136.017  95.038  57.743  36.449 
Ca_T0_5    Ca   45.30   94.70   66.55  43.77  16.298   7.112   3.768   3.979
Ca_T0_15   Ca  568.43 1183.01  621.01 351.90 125.603  93.409 111.506  65.257
Tg_T0_159  Tg  608.12  339.09  132.55  39.16   9.102  10.795  11.176   6.900
Tg_T0_160  Tg  332.15  193.08   61.55  33.82  11.388   6.011   4.657   3.598", header = T)


library(reshape2)

df.m <- melt(df)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df.m, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill=Esp)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you but no. I'm looking for a graphic where the "bars" from one species are pasted together and transparent so that all species are in one graphic but layered. 
that's what I wanted to use geom_hist instead of geom_bar. and I would like to have cumulative frequencies on the y-axis. 
but thank you very much.